# I have designed a sine wave inverter, but it has a feedback problem

Tags: inverter

I have designed an inverter (DC to AC,) which is sine wave and using a center tap transformer (500VA.) The circuit works fine without any short circuit.  The transformer I have used is 500VA and 350watt rated, but when the is load connected I am getting only 50 watt output from the transformer.  An Arduino Uno generates the 32kHz sPMW signal drivingthe MOSFETs.

I finally remembered that I need to add a feedback circuit, in which some part of the output is given to the microcontroller.

Here my major doubt is how the microcontroller should take action with respect to the change in transformer output coil (secondary winding) upon connecting the load.

1. Should it increase the duty cycle in each sPWM pulse?

2. Should it increase the frequency of the sPWM signal?

When the 32khz sPWM signal is given to the MOSFET without feedback and the driver circuit in no-load condition, the output voltage of the transformer is 233V AC.  When the  load is connected the output voltage decreases to 160V AC.

How can I keep the voltage stable?

[image]

Comment: For starters, those IRF840 aren't logic level MOSFET's. Driving them with 5V will barely turn them on. Even if they were to turn on fully, they have rather high Rds(on). I'd fix these things first as they'll be a major cause of poor output.

Comment: @Unimportant - The gate drive for the FETs comes from gate driver U1. It is not 5V.

Comment: @Kevin White True. Didn't notice it's a gate driver with separate logic supply.

Comment: Could you supply the transformer data sheet?

Comment: If your transformer is not a pulse transformer, you may have a problem. I don't think that a typical iron core sine wave transformer will do the job.